# Extracting Multiple Fields from an Array of Dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, parsing, multidimensional-array

I have an array of dictionaries that looks like this :

```
[{u'description': None, u'url': u'https://epi.testsite.net/index.php?/suites/view/196', u'is_completed': False, u'is_baseline': False, u'completed_on': None, u'is_master': False, u'project_id': 13, u'id': 196, u'name': u'Very Basic'}, {u'description': None, u'url': u'https://epi.testsite.net/index.php?/suites/view/200', u'is_completed': False, u'is_baseline': False, u'completed_on': None, u'is_master': False, u'project_id': 13, u'id': 200, u'name': u'Stress Testing'}]
```

and some Python code written to extract the 'id' field.  Code is as follows :

```
suites_list = client.send_get ('get_suites/' + pid)
suites_list_ids = [item['id'] for item in suites_list]
return (suites_list_ids)
```

suites_list generates the data above; suite_list_ids generates a tidy output as follows :

```
[196, 200]
```

I would like to pull a second field 'name' and have that included in the output.  The desired result like this :

```
[ {196,'Very Basic'}, {200, 'Stress Testing'} ]
```

I have been burning many cycles on this one and probably am overlooking something simple.  Appreciate any advice.

Dan.

Comment: Just a note, this is not an array of arrays, but rather an array of _dictionaries_, which are a different beast entirely. Renaming the question and your phrasing to reflect this should help you get clearer answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
suites_list_vals = [(item['id'], item['name']) for item in suites_list]
```

output:

```
[(196, 'Very Basic'), (200, 'Stress Testing')]
```

That is a list of tuples. To iterate on the object you can do something like this:

```
for val in suites_list_vals:
    print(val[0], ':', val[1])
```

output:

```
196 : Very Basic
200 : Stress Testing
```